# Chrome's top bar appearing in installed, standalone PWA

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, android-chrome

It seems I followed all rules for an installable PWA (including setting `display: standalone`), but even so, Android 9 still shows a top bar in my PWA that allows the user to close it or, through the three dots, refresh / open in Chrome / etc.

I guessed it could be related to the manifest's scope, but even that didn't work. Everything else works fine: the service worker, icons, splash screen... but this. Any hints?

The manifest is served from `website.com/static/blabla/manifest.json`, while the actual app is served from `website.com/orders`. I tried setting the `scope` and/or `start_url` to `https://website.com` or `https://website.com/orders`, to no avail.

I'm referring to this section I marked in red (there's no real application yet, so that's part of Chrome's UI, not my application):

[image: Chrome UI in installed PWA]

> Sorry if this is a dup, this is quite a hard topic to search - tons of actual Android development questions

Comment: You can convert your PWA to TWA to achieve this.

Comment: wait, you're suggesting to go from web development into creating a webview app using Android Studio? Or did I skim read [the article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa) too fast? This doesn't make sense at all (besides breaking the main idea of installable PWAs), it seems to work fine with the [MDN sample PWA](https://mdn.github.io/pwa-examples/js13kpwa/).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell not yet. PWA became a low priority for us, so it got pushed down the task list :(

Answer (score 0):

first, I would serve the manifest from the root of the PWA's origin, just a best practice.

Anyway, you need to set the display mode to standalone.

```
"display": "standalone",
```

Comment: sorry for not mentioning it in the question, but I've done it (will edit to make it clear). I'll try to change the manifest's path, but it doesn't seem related to the issue, does it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I eventually removed that bar for an Angular PWA.

```
"display": "standalone",
"scope": "/myScope/",
"start_url": "/app/welcome"
```

The trick (for me) was to use a sub-folder for the angular app, not put it into the scope folder.

```
https://www.sample.com/myScope/app/welcome
```

The issue seems to be that scope only includes sub-folders. Any files in the scope folder are not counted as being in-scope. I never found out if that was by design, a bug or just a misconfiguration. Just having that extra folder level, cured my scope problems.

I also had it working at a root level, but again the URL needed that extra level.

```
"display": "standalone",
"scope": "/",
"start_url": "/welcome"

https://www.sample.com/app/welcome
```